# 楽しました vs 楽しめました

Tags: word-choice

Which should I use to say "I had fun"? 楽しました or 楽しめました? Are they both correct?

Comment: I'd just keep it simple and say 楽しかった

Answer (score 5):

You have to say 楽しめました or 楽しみました.

- 楽【たの】しめました = masu-form of potential form of 楽【たの】しむ + まし + た = (lit.) I was able to have fun. = I had fun.
- 楽【たの】しみました = masu-form of 楽【たの】しむ + まし + た = I had fun.

These are both correct in this situation, and the difference is small.

楽【らく】しました happens to be grammatically correct, but means a totally different thing.

- 楽【らく】しました  = masu-form of 楽【らく】する + まし + た = I had an easy life. / I was being lazy.

楽【らく】する is the same as 楽【らく】をする, which is "to be lazy", "to have an easy life", "to do something without struggle/effort" etc.

Comment: As a side question, isn't らく also used in a military context, as in "at ease, soldier" ?

Comment: Just a hunch, but I think the OP might have been trying to conjugate the adjective 楽しい as a verb in the first example. It's worth pointing out that this isn't allowed.

Comment: @Urukann I don't think 楽 is used in that way. Did you mean: [休め](http://www.city.semboku.akita.jp/citizens/05_02_reisiki.html)

Comment: @naruto I may be confused... I thought I had seen this in a movie/anime, thanks for clearing it up !